# Google Tag Manager Help on Selecting a Tag & Trigger

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to track clicks to an icon on my site using Google Tag Manager. I've tried many combinations of tags & triggers but I can't get it working. Could you recommend me the right Tag & Trigger please?

Here are the details when I right click on the icon & Inspect Element:

**Copy Element**

```
<path d="M21.886 7.46c-.265-.483-.827-.599-1.271-.247l-1.74 1.38c-2.164 1.718-2.44 4.79-.618 6.86l5.96 6.772c1.822 2.07 5.011 2.316 7.13.542l1.313-1.1c.428-.357.444-.946.028-1.322l-2.904-2.63c-.412-.373-1.105-.404-1.54-.076l-1.714 1.296-4.843-5.353 1.743-1.259c.446-.321.595-.97.327-1.457l-1.87-3.406z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

**Copy Selector**

```
#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg > g > path
```

**Copy JS Path**

```
document.querySelector("#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg > g > path")
```

**Copy xPath**

```
//*[@id="comp-kt9muz3o"]/div[1]/svg/g/path
```

**Copy Full xPath**

```
/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/a[1]/div[1]/svg/g/path
```

These are the Data Layer Values in Google Tag Manager when I click on the icon:

```
{
  event: "lead",
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 9,
    start: 1635564494326,
    element: "SVGSVGElement: div._2qGZE._1Mc8D#QUICK_ACTION_BAR > div" +
             "._17TBS#QUICK_ACTION_BARactionsContainer > a._1LxZI._2c" +
             "rhc#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg",
    elementClasses: "",
    elementId: "",
    elementTarget: "",
    elementUrl: ""
  },
  url: "/contact-1?gtm_debug=1635564492290",
  title: "Contact | Title of Website"
}
```

So currently my choice of Tag is Google Analytics: GA4 Event. I don't know what to choose for the Trigger.

Comment: Put this in the console: `document.querySelectorAll("#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg > g > path")`. If only one element is returned, then you have a unique identifier. Is it? If so, you can proceed with setting up the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the css selector is actually unique.  You can do that by checking the number of elements in the node list returned from

```
document.querySelectorAll("#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg > g > path")
```

If it is unique, then you can proceed to setting up the trigger.  You want a click trigger

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679320?hl=en&ref_topic=7679108

and choose All Elements > This trigger fires on: Some Clicks > then choose built in variable from the dropdown on the lower left, which will bring up this interface:

[image]

You will want click classes, then > matches CSS selector and paste in your selector, ending up like this:

[image]

If you don't have a unique selector, then you'll have to figure out another way to uniquely identify the element and set up the trigger to work with that identifier.

Comment: I entered document.querySelectorAll("#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP > svg > g > path") in the trigger & GTM threw up this error message: Must Be a Valid CSS Selector

Which part of the string above is the actual CSS Selector?

Comment: The whole thing is the css selector.  Start from the beginning and try to work down to see where the error starts appearing, like with querySelectorAll("#comp-kt9muz3o") and keep pieces until the error starts, like next querySelectorAll("#comp-kt9muz3o > div._3mcAP").  The error might be in the " > ".  Try first with on ly ">".

Comment: but if you can alter the code on the target page, the absolutely easiest thing to do would be to give the element you want to track clicks for a unique ID and then just use that in the css selector box.